# Show GCloud Billing in Grafana

Tags: cloud, gcloud, grafana

I'd like to have my GCloud Billing shown in Realtime in Grafana, does anybody know about related projects to do just that?
My experience with Grafana itself is still quite limited, this doesn't make the task any easier.

I've read about Google [Cloud Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/), so this hints, that the task should be quite possible.

As I stated, I'm not proficient with Grafana yet
If no preexisting solution can be used, I'd be really grateful about an abstract description of the steps I'd have to take, in order to complete this task

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be useful to learn what others recommend and, I'm confident that someone else may have take this path too, but I think your best approach is to:

- Use Google's Billing Export to export your billing data to BigQuery [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery)
- Configure a Grafana BigQuery plugin [link](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/doitintl-bigquery-datasource/installation) to access the export data
- Build a Grafana dashboard

IIUC, the Billing API does not provide the level of detail that you require. It should but it's limited to metadata (Billing Accounts, SKUs) etc.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you for such a good answer. Not only did you show a path to solve this, you also explained why my attempt was insufficient in a humble way. 
I'm cheered to try this out now!

Comment: That's great! Thank you.